# Implement abstractmethod using the __getattr__ dunder method

Tags: python, interface, abstract-class, magic-methods, abstract-methods

I have a class that implements an interface, but I don't want to explicitly implement some of the methods. 
So I am using [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) dunder method for these methods, However I receive a `TypeError` when I do it.

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Worm with abstract methods run`

Example code:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class AnimalInterface(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def eat(self, food):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        ...

class Worm(AnimalInterface):
    def eat(self, food):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """this for methods that there is no need to specifically implement them"""
        return lambda *a, **kw: None
Worm()
```

Comment: Well, you simply cannot create an instance of a class which has abstract methods... You first need to implement all of them. Specifically, you did not implemented the `run` method of the `Worm` class.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco This is why I am using `__getattr__`, for all those "unimplemented" methods, Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but you *must* implement all your abstract methods before instantiating an object. Otherwise there is something wrong with the logic behind your solution. What do you want to achieve? Why don't you want to implement them?

Comment: The class is used by some code that expects to be able to use `run`. But in the case of `Worm`, `run` does nothing, so instead of implementing a method that does nothing I wanted to use ` __getattr__`. In reality I have more then a single "empty" method.

Comment: So why don't you simply implement those methods with `pass`?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco there is quite a lot of them

Comment: It looks like one should fix the ABC, not the derived class. Is there a reason why the ABC expects "quite a lot of them" methods when an implementation obviously does not need them? Do you know which methods are missing, or do you have to find our programmatically? Finally, are you aware that ``__getattr__`` will *not* work for proper method lookup, e.g. of special methods or decorators that respect the descriptor protocol?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete violation of interface segregation (SOLID). Maybe reconsider the design of your interface to make it more client specific?

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.